# TableView Json Array

Tags: json, swift

```
       {
         "YASSINIRLA" : "True",
          "KARBON" : "98",
          "GRUP" : "Orta Boy",
          "INDIRIMORANI" : "0",
          "KLIMA_TR" : "Var",
          "KREDI_FIYAT" : "107",
           "SIRANO" : "1",
          "YAKIT_EN" : "Diesel",

        }
```

Hi. I solved the problem but it is too long. I created an array for all of them. I also showed it in table view. How can I make it shorter? Sorry for my English. Thanks.

```
 dizi1.append(arac["YASSINIRLA"].string!)
 dizi2.append(arac["KARBON"].string!)
 dizi3.append(arac["INDIRIMORANI"].string!)
 dizi4.append(arac["KLIMA_TR"].string!)
 dizi5.append(arac["KREDI_FIYAT"].string!)

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return diziAracModelii.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "sonAracListelee") as! sonAracListeleViewCell

    cell.lblAracAdi1.text = dizi1[indexPath.row]
    cell.lblAracAdi2.text = dizi2[indexPath.row]
    cell.lblAracAdi3.text = dizi3[indexPath.row]
    cell.lblAracAdi4.text = dizi4[indexPath.row]
    cell.lblAracAdi5.text = dizi5[indexPath.row]


    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easier thing to do is to make a struct model, where you declare the variables. Then you can make an initiator function where you initiates the variables with the data from the json object. I recommend using SwiftyJSON while doing this.

If let in the init function make sure to check if the object contains any value.

```
struct CustomModel {
    public private(set) var yassinirla: String?
    public private(set) var karbon: String?
    public private(set) var indirimorani: String?
    public private(set) var klimaTr: String?
    public private(set) var krediFiyat: String?

    init(arac: JSON) {
         if let yassinirla = arac["YASSINIRLA"].string { 
             self.yassinirla = yassinirla
         }

         if let karbon = arac["KARBON"].string { 
             self.karbon = karbon
         }

         if let indirimorani = arac["INDIRIMORANI"].string { 
             self.indirimorani = indirimorani
         }

         if let klimaTr = arac["KLIMA_TR"].string else { 
             self.klimaTr = klima_tr
         }

         if let krediFiyat = arac["KREDI_FIYAT"].string else {
             self.krediFiyat = krediFiyat
         }
    }
}
```

In the header you can declare your array diziAracModelii as [CustomModel] so you don't have to use separate arrays for each string. That's just bad practice. You can handle this with a single array.

```
diziAracModelii: [CustomModel] = [CustomModel]()

func grabJson() {
    //...Download the json into a json constant

    //Send in the jsonobject in the CustomModel
    let newObject = CustomModel(arac: json)

    //Append to your string and make sure to reload the tableView data.
    diziAracModelii.append(newObject)
    self.yourTableView.reloadData()

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return diziAracModelii.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "sonAracListelee") as sonAracListeleViewCell else { return UITableViewCell() }

    cell.lblAracAdi1.text = diziAracModelii[indexPath.row].yassinirla
    cell.lblAracAdi2.text = diziAracModelii[indexPath.row].karbon
    cell.lblAracAdi3.text = diziAracModelii[indexPath.row].indirimorani
    cell.lblAracAdi4.text = diziAracModelii[indexPath.row].klimaTr
    cell.lblAracAdi5.text = diziAracModelii[indexPath.row].krediFiyat


    return cell
}
```